# How to get Polarion workitem field names(not values) of perticular work items using java SOAP API..?

Tags: java, soap, workitem, field-names, polarion

Polarion is a tool it has Workitems,fields they provide API for accessing it.
prersently i can access workitem field values But i want to access Defined Field names Using java SOAP API.

i tried with trackerservice from webserviceFactory but i didn't find proper methods to get polarion workitem fields(not values).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

An easy workaround is to check for the custom-field.xml directly in the Polarion Repository. It is available over http/DAV and should be as accessible as the webservice.